# Universal Laptop Power Supply (Multiple Output Plugs) Daily Use

Tags: laptop, power-supply

As you can already see in the title, I'm searching for an (alternative) power adapter which is compatible to my Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 15.

[image]

My old power supply was the original included one, when I brought the notebook. Unfortunately, I've lost my old one and need a replacement.
I've asked the Lenovo support, if it is possible to get a new one that matches my device. Yes it was, but I found out it was too expensive.

After a short search I saw these https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=universal+notebook+adapter universal notebook adapter. The price and the idea captured my interest, so I decide that one of these should be my new power supply. However, because of the huge selection and options, I don't know what would work for me. I must also say that I don't have any knowledge about power supplies.

This will become my main power supply, so it should not be for occasional use. Also it should be very versatile to use, because I have many 
other different laptops and traveling around the world, so a flexible power input and output would be nice.

What power adapter would you recommend? (I live in Germany)

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the off topic questions (we only recommend products here). I noticed that you are wanting to use this for more than one laptop. Can you list the laptops that you have to make sure that the power supply will be compatible (if possible) please?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:
[Coolermaster MasterWatt Next Gen 90w](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA91N4DF3498&cm_re=Coolermaster_laptop_power_supply-_-34-989-710-_-Product)

```
Universal convenience
Up to 90% efficiency
Nine different tips, including square Lenovo solution
Meets latest US Level VI energy standards
100,000 hour(s) life expectancy
```